# Summarize with conditions based on ranges in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

There is an illustration of my example.
Sample data:

```
 df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5), A = c("foo", "bar", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar"),
 B =     c(1, 5, 7, 23, 54, 202))

df
  ID   A   B
1  1 foo   1
2  1 bar   5
3  2 foo   7
4  2 foo  23
5  3 bar  54
6  5 bar 202
```

What I want to do is to summarize, by ID, and count of the same IDs. Furthermore, I want frequencies of IDs in subgroups based values of B in different numeric ranges (number of observations with B>=0 & B<5, B>=5 & B<10, B>=10 & B<15, B>=15 & B<20 etc for all IDs).

I want this result:

```
  ID count count_0_5 count_5_10 etc
1  1    2          1          1 etc
2  2    2         NA          1 etc
3  3    1         NA         NA etc
4  5    1         NA         NA etc
```

I tried this code using package `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(count=n(), count_0_5 = n(B>=0 & B<5))
```

However, it returns this error:

```
`Error in n(B>=0 & B<5) : 
  unused argument (B>=0 & B<5)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(B_cut = cut(B, c(0,5,10,15,20,1000), labels = c('count_0_5','count_5_10','count_10_15','count_15_20','count_20_1000')), count=n()) %>% 
   group_by(ID,B_cut) %>% mutate(n=n()) %>% slice(1) %>% select(-A,-B) %>% 
   spread(B_cut, n)

#2nd option
left_join(df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(n=n()), 
          df %>% mutate(B_cut = cut(B, c(0,5,10,15,20,1000), labels = c('count_0_5','count_5_10','count_10_15','count_15_20','count_20_1000'))) %>% 
                 count(ID,B_cut) %>% spread(B_cut,n), 
          by='ID')

# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   ID [4]
     ID count count_0_5 count_5_10 count_20_1000
  <dbl> <int>     <int>      <int>         <int>
1     1     2         2         NA            NA
2     2     2        NA          1             1
3     3     1        NA         NA             1
4     5     1        NA         NA             1
```

Comment: @Vojtěch Kania sorry I had a bug in the previous answer please check this one.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps replacing `n(B>=0 & B<5)` with `sum(B>=0 & B<5)`?

This will sum the number of cases where the two specified conditions are accomplished.

However, you'll get `0's` instead of `NA's`. This can be settled by:
`ifelse(sum(B>=0 & B<5)>0, sum(B>=0 & B<5), NA)`

I'm pretty sure that there may be a better solution (more clearer and efficient), but this should work!